# D3 stacked bar chart not able to see full x axis lables

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

i have created the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i6lg.png)following stacked bar chart us D3.

as you can i cant see the full x axis labels,

bellow is my javascript code

```
var stackedBarChartData = [{
    key: 'Port Klang',
    'color' : COLOR_REDS,
    values: [
        { x:"Allocated", y: 10}, { x:"Unallocated", y: 21}, { x:"Unallocated Expired", y: 45}, { x:"Expiring within 10 days", y: 76}, { x:"Floating", y: 55}, { x:"Hub Inventory", y: 68},{ x:"Total Inventory", y: 32}
    ]
},{
    key: 'Jebel Ali',
    'color' : COLOR_ORANGES,
    values: [
        { x:"Allocated", y: 33}, { x:"Unallocated", y: 76}, { x:"Unallocated Expired", y: 82}, { x:"Expiring within 10 days", y: 67}, { x:"Floating", y: 61}, { x:"Hub Inventory", y: 44},{ x:"Total Inventory", y: 15}

    ]
}];

nv.addGraph({
    generate: function() {
        var stackedBarChart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
            .stacked(true)
            .showControls(false)

        stackedBarChart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.0f'));

        var svg = d3.select('#nv-stacked-bar-chartmy')
        .append('svg')
        .datum(stackedBarChartData);
        svg.transition().duration(0).call(stackedBarChart);
        return stackedBarChart;
    }
});
```

some of labels not visible. if i increase width of the chart then i can see all the x axis labels. however i dont want to increase the size. anyother way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi Elite. It seems the code you have given is a bit incomplete. I am getting errors that COLOR_REDS and COLOR_ORANGES is undefined. Could you please add more complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately svg text remains inline and would require more complex code to split the text into two lines. An example of multi-line axis labels can be found here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321.

If your axis labels are not too long, there are two easier alternative solutions:

1. Reduce the size of the font for the labels. Add the code before the `return stackedBarChart;` statement:

   ```
   var ticks = d3.select('.nv-x').selectAll('.tick'); //select the ticks on the x-axis
   ticks.select('text')
    .style('opacity', '1') //unhide the labels
    .style('font-size', 8); //change the font-size
   ```
2. Other option is to rotate the labels. Add the code before the `return stackedBarChart;` statement:

   ```
    svg.attr('height', 400); //increase the height of the svg to make room for the labels
    var ticks = d3.select('.nv-x').selectAll('.tick');
    ticks.selectAll('text')
     .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,10) rotate(-90)') //rotates and shifts the text a bit
     .style('text-anchor', 'end') //sets the text to align to the end
     .style('opacity', 1); //makes all the labels visible
   ```

You could also use a combination of both above.